# upload image in base64 format and compressed image before sending to server with retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, image-compression

I've make upload image with retrofit that i follow from tutorial in internet. 
here are my code:

**AcademicClient.class**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/")
    Call<ResponseBody> postImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image, @Part("name")RequestBody name);
```

**MainFeed.class**

```
File file = new File(filePath);
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload",file.getName(),reqFile);
        RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),"upload_test");

        Log.d("xxxxxxx",body + " ---- "+ name);

        AcademicClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(AcademicClient.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = client.postImage(body,name);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

How to convert it Base64 and compress the image first before it sending to server in retrofit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

First define `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `byte[]` object:

```
bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] BYTE;
```

Second define uncompressed `Bitmap` (bitmap1) like below:

```
 bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,40,bytearrayoutputstream);

 BYTE = bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray();
```

Third convert `byte[]` to `Base64`

```
 String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(BYTE, Base64.DEFAULT);
 Bitmap compressedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BYTE,0,BYTE.length);
```

Fourth, finally you get `Compressed` and `Base64` converted image:

Now you can send `Base64` image directly without using `MultiPart`.

Comment: I'am bit confused, i'm still new In android development. Is there some change in my academicClient class and maindfeed class? because You said i can send without using Multipart?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @niveshshastri how I send Bae64 string to server without MultiPart?

Comment: @PradeepSodhi you don't need to use multipart here, just use key value formate in POST API