# Image file inside nested json body with RetroFit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, image-uploading, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm trying to upload an image from my Android app using Retrofit 2.0. The request body has to be like this. I'm used to using @MultiPart for image uploads, but I can't figure out how to put the image inside a nested JSON.

```
{
     "user": {
         "profile": {
              "id": id
              "image": {
                   "photo": photo
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried encoding the image binary data to a base64 string?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360505/461822). I believe it addresses a very similar issue.

Comment: @SaiPuli I'm checking if there's a way to do it using MultiPart.